# Resources for advanced spoken English

Tags: discussion

I am looking for resources for advanced spoken English, where less common vocabulary and grammar are used. To illustrate, Jordan Peterson uses such words as *proclivity* or *finitude* in his talks, which are, in my opinion, less frequent words in English compared to their synonyms. And, he does that quite naturally and appropriately.
Do you know any other speakers or lecturers with the same feature?

Thanks

Comment: I love this man. Check out [intellectual dark web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_dark_web) and people associated with it. It might be a bit random, but I'd also recommend Russell Brand (particularly if you are into British English)

Answer (score 1):

I think some of US Chief Justice Roberts speeches and interviews on CSPAN might be a good resource, for example [Chief Justice Roberts Remarks at University of Minnesota Law School](https://www.c-span.org/video/?451977-1/chief-justice-roberts-stresses-supreme-courts-independence-contentious-kavanaugh-hearings). The nice thing about listening on CSPAN is that there is a transcript divided by timestamps, so you can read as he is speaking. Justice Roberts speaks at a reasonable pace, his accent seems to me to be a fairly neutral general American accent, and he chooses words precisely. When he is giving a speech, his language is very formal. When he is talking conversationally, it's a little more informal, but he doesn't use a lot of slang or colloquialisms.

The topics he speaks about might be a little challenging. His recorded interviews are about US law, and often refer to legal precedents and concepts that are well-known among Americans interested in law, but others may not understand all the things he references. He doesn't use as many "academic" words as Jordan Peterson, but he does use longer sentences than many speakers and I have yet to catch him making a grammatical mistake (that doesn't mean he never has, it's just rare for him).

Comment: On the *written* side, Justices Kagan, Scalia, and Ginsberg are/were all known for clear, easily understood legal writing. Scalia had a tendency to use more... creative (colloquial/idiomatic) constructions, however.

Answer (score 1):

The question is telescopic so I can only share part of my microscopic view.

- There are many, many resources, especially shows on PBS (Public Broadcasting), in the States.
- A really great resource is CUNY TV, from the City University of NY:

[Irish writer_ one example, check out the main site](https://tv.cuny.edu/show/irishwriters)

Also see at  CUNY, Bill Moyers.

- There is also the The New Yorker Radio Hour through National Public Radio:
  [Radio Hour](https://www.npr.org/podcasts/458929150/the-new-yorker-radio-hour)
- Conversations with philosophers, presented by Brian Magee (RIP):

[conversations with philosophers via Youtube](https://www.openculture.com/2019/07/bryan-magee-rip-presents-in-depth-uncut-tv-conversations-with-famous-philosophers.htm)

I think all of those provide plenty of high-level speakers with advanced vocabularies.